# Не могли бы вы посоветовать "легковесную" IDE для C++?

Tags: c++, c, ide, поиск-программ

Нужна какая-нибудь простенькая идешка для программирования на плюсах. Какие-то большие проекты не создаю, просто делаю лабы в вузе по проге и алгоритмам. В основном использую Clion, но хотелось бы чего-то попроще. Есть идея перейти вообще на редактор кода, а именно Sublime Text. Только не знаю насколько она здравая.

Comment: VSCode попробуйте, возможно понравится

Comment: Что для вас означает "какая-нибудь простенькая"? Что не устраивает в Clion?

Comment: VSCode, c плагином Clangd вместо дефолтного C++-плагина.

Comment: Когда мне нужна была «легковесная» IDE я использовал Code::Blocks. Остался доволен. Но не думаю, что существует универсальный ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: Обычная Visual Studio - легче, чем VSCode и более функциональная.

Answer (score 1):

Sublimetext(как текстовый редактор) + консольный компилятор [gcc/g++](https://programforyou.ru/poleznoe/kak-ustanovit-gcc-dlya-windows) покроет все ваши нужды. Оба продукта не требуют денежных вливаний. Сам компилятор весит не более 100мб и sublimetext тоже много не занимает. К тому же компилируя что-то через командную строку вы будете выглядеть как хакер :D и это будет полезно на этапе образования для понимания того как вообще код превращается в программу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На продукты VS рекомендую пока не смотреть,они излишне сложны на этапе обучения и могут только вредить лишними предупреждениями или подсказками, суть которых вам не ясна. Если вы правда заинтересованы в том, чтобы хорошо владеть с и с++ пересаживайтесь на linux, там научитесь управлять ОС с помощью командной строки и вообще всё делать с помощью консоли, сможете взаимодействовать с ОС по POSIX и установка библиотек или компиляторов будет сводиться к 1 команде, а не "пойти в браузер, найти сайт, найти версию, скачать, распаковать, установить" как на винде.

Comment: а точки останова? а подчеркивание ошибок?

Comment: eri в вопрсе автор не спрашивал про средства отладки, но даже если так -gdb(или старый добрый printf, которого вполне достаточно при выполнении лр). Что такое подчёркивание ошибок в вашем сообщении, мне не очень понятно, ведь sublime подчёркивает ошибки, пусть меньше, но опять-таки для учёбы же

Answer (score 0):

VSCode будет чем-то средним между Clion и Sublimetext. Главное не переборщить с плагинами. Подсказки и автодополнения очень полезная штука и позволяет не так часто заглядывать в документацию и чужой код.

Но если у Вас есть подписка на Clion, то можно пользоваться им в легком режиме - в меню найдите кнопку "режим энергосбережения" и он станет легковесным.